# function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, blockui, jquery-blockui

[This Link is a sample](http://iranfairco.com/example/test2.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: 'orange'} , message: '<img src="icon/wait.gif" /><div style=\'font-family:Tahoma;font-size:large\'> ...???? ??? ???? ??? ????</div>' });                 

function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}

function test()
{
    var  certification = "";
    var address;
    var  idCompany="821229021";
    var Empty = true;
    for (var  i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                 
    { 
        idCompany =idCompany + i.toString();
        idCompany=idCompany + ".png";
        address="Image/CertificationCompany/"+idCompany; 

        if (UrlExists(address))
        {
            //certification += "<img style='margin:5px;padding:5px;cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid GrayText;' width='103px' height='80px;' src='Image/CertificationCompany/" + idCompany + "' />";                               
             certification +="<a href='Image/CertificationCompany/" + idCompany + "' rel='prettyPhotoCertification[pp_gal]' title=' ?????? ????????? ???? "+document.title+"'><img style='margin:5px;padding:5px;cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid GrayText;' width='103px' height='80px;' src='Image/CertificationCompany/" + idCompany + "'  alt='????????? ??' /></a>";                      

            Empty = false;
        }

        idCompany="821229021";
        //$.unblockUI();
    }

    if(Empty ){
        certification = "updating<br /><img src='icon/Updated.png' />";
    }
    $("#contentCertification").html(certification);
}

$.unblockUI();

</script>
```

HTML

```
 <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="test();"/>
```

2) In IE, `$.blockUI()` does not work and it appears that the browser has hung.

[This Link is a sample](http://iranfairco.com/example/test2.aspx)

Comment: Why are you using inline JavaScript, `onclick=`, when you have jQuery?

Comment: What's really good about those samples is that none of them load.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">
```

should be

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: I think it is easier to just ommit those and go with plain `<script>`

Comment: i do not understand please write a sample

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading jQuery and the plugins? Ensure that you don't use a self closing script tag, doesn't work on IE.

```
<script src="js/blockui.js" />       <!-- WRONG -->
<script src="js/blockui.js></script> <!-- CORRECT -->
```